# How to test a java class with method

Tags: java

I am newbie to java, so please excuse my ignorance. I tried to find this answer online but could not get the exact solution, so please help

I have created a java class, which has a method that accepts three parameters, the program accepts that parameter and insert those three parameters in the database.

Now I want to test this program and not sure how to do, I want that when I run this program, program should force me to enter three values which are input to the method

Kindly help

Comment: So, you want to check at runtime whether the arguments are correct? Or are you asking about how you can get your code to execute?

Comment: I have create a another class (say Class B), created the object of class A and invoked the method of class A and passed these values. The program runs fine, no errors, but rows were not inserted in the database, so I thought can I just test like what i mentioned in the questions

Comment: You could either step through, using a debugger (I assume you are using an IDE, such as Eclipse or IntelliJ), or you could write Unit tests to check whether each method does what you want it to.

Comment: @KuluLimpa- I just want to test my class is working fine. I want to pass these three values to the method that I have and used these values to insert in the database

Comment: @Girish So you just want a program which will ask you to enter three values and that's it?

Comment: @KuluLimpa- I am using Eclipse

Comment: So, for your case where the values are not inserted in the Database, put a breakpoint at the method you want to investigate and run the application in debug mode. In the debug view of Eclipse, you will be able t investigate what is going on. I'm sorry if I do not fully understand the question. Maybe you can add the code that seems not to work as intended? Edit: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html here's a tutorial on how to debug with Eclipse with a lot of pictures. Edit2: Also, the problem may be in your database connection. It's hard to tell

Comment: You should look at a tool like JUnit, TestNG, or Spock.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a program to read some input and call a function with three String arguments, this code will work. Just look up the Scanner class in java.util.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GetParameters
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s1 = scan.nextLine();
        String s2 = scan.nextLine();
        String s3 = scan.nextLine();
    }

    public static void yourMethod(String s1, String s2, String s3)
    {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like a XY-Problem. OP is asking for what you answered, but it is not his actual problem ...